# Cordova fileupload errors in xcode - "WebKit discarded an uncaught exception"

Tags: cordova

I'm having a hard time getting the FileTransfer to work in Cordova 1.6.0. I haven't tried it in earlier version, so I don't know if this is a new issue or not.

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload( 
    imageURLToLocalFile, 
    urlToMyServiceEndpoint, 
    successhandler,
    errorhandler,
    options
);
```

In the Xcode console I see.

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the
webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: 
delegate: <NSRangeException> ***
 -[JKArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)
```

Seems to me that when the Cordova exec function is calling the native Filehandler functions this happens, but I have no idea how to interpret the error message.

I am a little bit suspicious about the call that creates the error, the FileTransfer.prototype.upload function in the Cordova file. I the 1.6.0 version it is:

```
exec(
    successCallback, 
    errorCallback, 
    'FileTransfer', 
    'upload', 
    [filePath, server, fileKey, fileName, mimeType, params, trustAllHosts, chunkedMode]
);
```

While the older 1.5.0 version is:

```
Cordova.exec(
    successCallback,
    errorCallback,
    'org.apache.cordova.filetransfer', 
    'upload', 
    [options]
);
```

Comment: Have you had any luck with this error?

Comment: No, I had to use another solution and ended up not using the FileTransfer method at all, but used jquery ajax function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Cordova 1.6.x which is due to be resolved in Cordova 1.7.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-543).

The workaround is to manually specify all the options (fileName, fileKey, etc.) as the framework is incorrectly treating them as mandatory.

So:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
```

Becomes:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = "image.jpg";
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
options.chunkedMode = true;
options.params = {}; // This line is untested as I have actual params
```

Rich

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the upload method has changed. I had similar issue that was solved by adding true after options:

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(

  imageURLToLocalFile, 
  urlToMyServiceEndpoint, 
  successhandler,
  errorhandler,
  options,
  **true**
);
```